# Get data from a list in a console app to web app in c#

Tags: c#, console

I have a solution with a couple of console applications and a webapplication. 
In one of the console applications im collecting some data into a List.
This list i want to get data from into a list in the web application.
However when im trying to get the data from the console app into the web app the data is always zero/null.

Is it possible to move data between applications within the same solution?
And how can i solve the problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How are you transferring the data that ends up bring NULL in the WebApp?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .NET Remoting for interprocess comunication (IPC). Here is a good article:
http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/3520891/Improved-NET-Remoting-Part-1-Same-Box-Communication.htm

Comment: One more article: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/using-ipc-channels-and-net-framework-20-to-communicate-between-processes/6143016

Answer (score 0):

You could call a webservice method in the web application from the console app and pass the list.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any examples out there on this one?

Comment: Yea, it's easy to add webservice to your webapp and when you want to consume it from a client VS pretty much does the wiring for you.  See this tutorial to get you going - http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/34279-introduction-to-web-services-in-c%23/